# article+beamerarticle needs some adjustments that one could expect to avoid

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

The `beamer`'s documentation stipulates:

> The article mode of a presentation is created by specifying `article` or `book` or some other class as the document class instead of `beamer` and by then loading the package `beamerarticle`.
>
> The package `beamerarticle` defines virtually all of beamer’s commands in a way that is sensible for the `article` mode.

Hence one could expect to be virtually able to create an `article` version from an existing document initially done with `beamer` class for a presentation with no more than just using `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle}` instead of `\documentclass{beamer}`.

But, unfortunately, that's not the case, as pointed out by the following example:

```
% \documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle}
%
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which complains that `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` is undefined.

Okay, I could use this command only in `presentation` mode:

```
\mode<presentation>{%
  \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}%
}
```

but why such commands are not redefined to `\relax` by `beamerarticle`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question here really is. Only the author of `beamer` can say why, so it would probably be better to ask them if you really want an answer to the question asked. If you really want an answer to a different question, you should ask that instead.

Comment: @cfr Indeed my question is unclear. The point is I didn't know if I was missing some trivial reason for `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` to not be redefined to something harmless by `beamerarticle`.

Answer (score 3):

- `beamerarticle` requires package `beamerbasearticle`
- `beamerbasearticle` requires package `beamerbaserequires`
- `beamerbaserequires` requires package `beamerbaseoverlay`
- in `beamerbaseoverlay`:

  - it changes to `\mode<presentation>` on line 259
  - it defines `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` on line 503
  - it changes back to `\mode<all>` on line 843

So my best guess is that `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` is intentionally left undefined in article mode.

Comment: Nice caving expedition! :) Nevertheless, if I'm right (see my comment to Joseph's answer), `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` may reasonably be used in the common LaTeX code shared by the  "`beamer`" and the "`beamerarticle`" documents.

Answer (score 3):

As the current `beamer` maintainer, I can speculate about past design approaches and ask that you [log an issue](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/new) requesting any specific changes.

My suggestion is that you need to start from the idea that a no single 'real' source file will contain both

```
\documentclass{beamer}
```

and

```
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
```

Instead, one would expect two stub files, one something of the form

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% Rest of preamble
\begin{document}
\input{document-body}
\end{document}
```

and a second

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
% Rest of preamble
\begin{document}
\input{document-body}
\end{document}
```

The reasoning is that whilst the *content* might be the same, the *setup* for the two cases is rather different.

In the specific case of `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification`, the command really doesn't make sense in an article (there are no overlays), only in a presentation. As such, there is no expectation to come across the command in a 'real' preamble for an `article` and thus no need to define it.

You will find the same for a number of other `beamer` concepts that don't apply to articles.

Comment: Before opening an issue, I wanted to ask here if it did make sense to request any specific changes about that subject. I'm aware of the benefit to deal with two distinct files (and that's the way I'm working). However, `document-body.tex` may reasonably contain `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` for instance in the case one globally asks `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` in  the "`beamer`" document's preamble but wants to disable this setting for, say, some specific frame with `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}` followed by `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` afterwards.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé A better example would be one where you wanted to change the default for a number of consecutive frames, rather than for just one, since you can change it for a single frame more easily as an argument to the frame itself.

Comment: @cfr Indeed, you're right (I wasn't aware of that option of the `frame` environment).

Comment: Another example of command which needs adjustments is `\footnote` when used with some `⟨overlay specification⟩`, for instance: `\footnote<.->`.